# Issue with Unset (PHP)

Tags: php, session

I am trying to unset an item from session array, it unset once then brings back again.
**for exg :-**

**if i click to remove itemId = 5, it removes from session array,
then i click to remove itemId = 6, then i see the old itemId = 5 is back in array again.**

/*** delete item from cart ***/

```
       public function deleteCartItem($id, $customerId, $cartId, $wishlistFlag=false) // Param: ProductID, CustomerID, CartID, WishlistFlag
        {
            $conn = $_SESSION['conn'];
            $itemId = false;
            $chk = array();
           
                    $sql = "DELETE FROM cart_items WHERE product_id=? AND cart_id=?";
                    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);//$result = $conn->query($sql);
                    $stmt->bind_param('ii', $item['id'],$cartId);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $itemId = $i;
                    echo $itemId; 
                    $chk[] = $_SESSION['cart'];
                    echo'</br>'; 
                    print_r($chk);
                }
            }
            if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$itemId])){
                unset($_SESSION['cart'][$itemId]);
       }    
} 





<?php

    $_SESSION['cart'] = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 6154353459,
    'name' => 'pro one Night Out Mesh Tee',
    'display_brand' => 'Widow',
    'qty' => 1,
    'price' => '28.0000',
    'special_price' => 0,
    'rule_price' => '',
    'attributes' => 
    array (
      0 => 'BLACK',
      1 => 'XX-Large',
    ),
    'option80' => 18,
    'option125' => 3457,
    'child_product_id' => 61535897,
    'giftcard' => '',
    'whole_preorder' => 0,
    'preorder_shipping_date' => NULL,
    'available_qty' => 5,
    'isRefundable' => true,
    'max_sale_qty' => false,
    'isFree' => 0,
    'segment' => 
    array (
      'magento_product_id' => '65315459',
      'product_id' => 'P19335935',
      'quantity' => 1,
      'name' => 'pro one Night Out Mesh Tee',
      'brand' => 'Widow',
      'price' => 28.0,
      'special_price' => NULL,
      'regular_price' => 28.0,
      'size_type' => 'Regular',
      'manufacturer' => 'Widow',
      'trend' => 'WID goodie Hour 2020',
      'microcategory' => 'Mesh Shirt',
      'doll_category' => NULL,
      'stock_quantity' => 10,
      'sku' => 'S493660',
      'child_stock_quantity' => 1,
      'size' => 'XX-Large',
      'swatch' => 'BLACK',
    ),
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'id' => 615345465,
    'name' => 'pro one Night Out Mesh Leggings',
    'display_brand' => 'Widow',
    'qty' => 1,
    'price' => '30.0000',
    'special_price' => 0,
    'rule_price' => '',
    'attributes' => 
    array (
      0 => 'BLACK',
      1 => 'Medium',
    ),
    'option80' => 18,
    'option125' => 3454,
    'child_product_id' => 6315890,
    'giftcard' => '',
    'whole_preorder' => '',
    'preorder_shipping_date' => NULL,
    'available_qty' => 37,
    'isRefundable' => true,
    'max_sale_qty' => false,
    'isFree' => 0,
    'segment' => 
    array (
      'magento_product_id' => '64334515465',
      'product_id' => 'P193936',
      'quantity' => 1,
      'name' => 'pro one Night Out Mesh Leggings',
      'brand' => 'Widow',
      'price' => 30.0,
      'special_price' => NULL,
      'regular_price' => 30.0,
      'size_type' => 'Regular',
      'manufacturer' => 'Widow',
      'trend' => 'WID goodie Hour 2020',
      'microcategory' => 'Printed Leggings',
      'doll_category' => NULL,
      'stock_quantity' => 10,
      'sku' => 'S493664',
      'child_stock_quantity' => 10,
      'size' => 'Medium',
      'swatch' => 'BLACK',
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => 615445348,
    'name' => 'pro two My Lashes Sunglasses',
    'display_brand' => '',
    'qty' => 1,
    'price' => '15.0000',
    'special_price' => 0,
    'rule_price' => '',
    'attributes' => 
    array (
      0 => 'BLACK',
      1 => 'ONE SIZE',
    ),
    'option80' => 18,
    'option125' => 6212,
    'child_product_id' => 6154345358,
    'giftcard' => '',
    'whole_preorder' => '',
    'preorder_shipping_date' => NULL,
    'available_qty' => 295,
    'isRefundable' => true,
    'max_sale_qty' => false,
    'isFree' => 0,
    'segment' => 
    array (
      'magento_product_id' => '6153453448',
      'product_id' => 'P19645642180',
      'quantity' => 1,
      'name' => 'pro two My Lashes Sunglasses',
      'brand' => '',
      'price' => 15.0,
      'special_price' => NULL,
      'regular_price' => 15.0,
      'size_type' => 'Regular',
      'manufacturer' => 'CIEL',
      'trend' => 'WID goodie Hour 2020',
      'microcategory' => 'Cat Eye Sunglasses',
      'category' => 'Accessories,Sunglasses,Cat Eye Sunglasses',
      'special_category' => 'What\'s New,Char Test Category,Widow',
      'doll_category' => NULL,
      'stock_quantity' => 10,
      'sku' => 'S486477',
      'child_stock_quantity' => 10,
      'size' => 'ONE SIZE',
      'swatch' => 'BLACK',
    ),
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'id' => 61465645461,
    'name' => 'pro one Night Out goodie Dress',
    'display_brand' => 'Widow',
    'qty' => 1,
    'price' => '45.0000',
    'special_price' => 0,
    'rule_price' => '',
    'attributes' => 
    array (
      0 => 'BLACK',
      1 => 'X-Large',
    ),
    'option80' => 18,
    'option125' => 3456,
    'giftcard' => '',
    'whole_preorder' => '',
    'preorder_shipping_date' => NULL,
    'available_qty' => 12,
    'isRefundable' => true,
    'max_sale_qty' => false,
    'isFree' => 0,
    'segment' => 
    array (
      'magento_product_id' => '616465461',
      'product_id' => 'P1935446934',
      'quantity' => 1,
      'name' => 'pro one Night Out goodie Dress',
      'brand' => 'Widow',
      'price' => 45.0,
      'special_price' => NULL,
      'regular_price' => 45.0,
      'size_type' => 'Regular',
      'manufacturer' => 'Widow',
      'trend' => 'WID goodie Hour 2020',
      'microcategory' => 'goodie Dresses',
      'category' => 'Clothing,Dresses,Mini,goodie Dresses',
      'special_category' => 'Brandsgoodie,Char Test Category,Widow,Widow',
      'doll_category' => NULL,
      'stock_quantity' => 10,
      'sku' => 'S493652',
      'child_stock_quantity' => 10,
      'size' => 'X-Large',
      'swatch' => 'BLACK',
    ),
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'id' => 6154566225,
    'name' => 'Feelings Maxi Dress',
    'display_brand' => 'Widow',
    'qty' => 1,
    'price' => '58.0000',
    'special_price' => 0,
    'rule_price' => '',
    'attributes' => 
    array (
      0 => 'BLACK',
      1 => 'Large',
    ),
    'option80' => 18,
    'option125' => 3455,
    'child_product_id' => 61456455677,
    'giftcard' => '',
    'whole_preorder' => '',
    'preorder_shipping_date' => NULL,
    'available_qty' => 30,
    'isRefundable' => true,
    'max_sale_qty' => false,
    'isFree' => 0,
    'segment' => 
    array (
      'magento_product_id' => '614565225',
      'product_id' => 'P1945652050',
      'quantity' => 1,
      'name' => 'Phantom Feelings Maxi Dress',
      'brand' => 'Widow',
      'price' => 58.0,
      'special_price' => NULL,
      'regular_price' => 58.0,
      'size_type' => 'Regular',
      'manufacturer' => 'Widow',
      'trend' => 'WID goodie Hour 2020',
      'microcategory' => 'Maxi Dresses',
      'category' => 'Dresses,Midi & Maxi,Maxi Dresses',
      'special_category' => 'Brandsgoodie,Char Test Category,Widow,Widow',
      'doll_category' => NULL,
      'stock_quantity' => 10,
      'sku' => 'S485794',
      'child_stock_quantity' => 10,
      'size' => 'Large',
      'swatch' => 'BLACK',
    ),
  )
  );

$itemId = 5; // comes dybamically;
   if (   isset($_SESSION['cart'][$itemId])) {
            unset($_SESSION['cart'][$itemId]);
    }
?>
```

I am not getting it,
Any thoughts ?

You can also take a look at the sandbox- http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6bab394d1da39a301ce82b974022da7b7efaface

Please refer to the whole code here - [PHP SESSION UPDATE ISSUE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64763520/php-session-update-issue)

Thankyou

Comment: There is no item 5 in your cart

Comment: You need to demonstrate a little more of the architecture. What happens when you 'click to remove'? Please share all code involved.

Comment: Your questions is to unclear

Comment: If you are resubmitting the same page or hard-coded the item into the session array, it's normal that it's coming back.

Comment: yes it will coming back because it will overriden the data again

Comment: Jerson you got the issue ?

Comment: I have added a sandbox link.

Comment: Let me know if i can still make question more clear. Thankyou very much

Comment: Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: @Rambarun Komaljeet how to prevent it ?

Comment: Is this the same issue you were describing in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64763520/php-session-update-issue)?

Comment: Yes @El_Vanja  right

Comment: I am really not sure which code can cause this type of behavior. I need some suggestions. how can i debug it.

Comment: In your previous question you stated "I have found that when i remove products one after another rapidly then it causes issue". This pretty much sounds like a problem with concurrent AJAX requests. Is the action triggered through AJAX?

Comment: Yes @El_Vanja using AJAX, but now i remove product after 20 second interval same issue. by the way thankyou for showing interest to question.

Comment: I can see that their ismany ajax request have "aysnc async: true". If its true i face issue with session, when i delete some items in session it comes back. This ajax request is called beforeI want to create an ajax request of removing item from session.

Whenfor a functionality, but i set it to am not sure is their any drawback of "falseasync: true, it works fine".

I am not sure how & whyWhat are the drawbacks of "async: true" in ajax ?

Answer (score 2):

You're proably re-reading session-data so that deletion you're making is overridden.

```
<?php
$cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
unset($cart[5]);
echo 'deletion confirmed';

//later in execution..
//accidental re-read of cart from session-variable.
//BAD CODE STARTS HERE
$cart = $_SESSION['cart']; //error since you're re-reading cart from session.
//BAD CODE END
//calc totals in basket or something..
$totals = 0;
foreach($cart as $item) {
  $totals = $totals + $item['qty'] * $item['price'];
}

//somewhere in the script, the session variable is updated.
$_SESSION['cart'] = $cart;
```

**GOOD TO KNOW**
PHP passes most variables by value as default, meaning that

$cart = $_SESSION['cart'];

*copies* the content of $_SESSION['cart'] into $cart.

Any change made to $cart will **not** automatically be updated in $_SESSION['cart'].

If you don't want a copy but a reference, you may use:

```
$cart = &$_SESSION['cart'];
```

and you will not need to save $cart into $_SESSION.

(Just make sure $_SESSION['cart'] is initialized when making the reference)

** AND **

Session variables tend to grow to a mess.. Use getters and setters in your application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what is "$cart = $_SESSION['cart']; //oops.." ?

Comment: That's where thinks go wrong since your deletion if index[5] is invalidated by re-reading the session-data.

Comment: Can you please update answer with correct code & remove the infected code ? That would be helpful

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working i can see $_SESSION['cart']; have old data which was unset on second time removing product

Comment: Any thoughts Teson?

Comment: unset will create holes in the indexed array and may create strange errors, please see http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ae5a0ac633f37eed5f9b0cda64a59b6d9f0541e1

Comment: What can be the alternate solution for this ? Or some fix ?

Comment: Can you please tell me that this kind of code can be cause of this issue "$cart = $_SESSION['cart']; //oops.." ?

Comment: @dev - you may have an error in your logic (incoming $itemId to be deleted), since it should rather be called $cart_row_id. It's the ROW you're passing - no PK or itemNo - problem could be here). If you remove a *row* in the indexed array, then use $cart = array_values($cart) you should be fine unless you have more errors / problems in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to after unset get the updated array from session and declare it again

```
$cart_array = array (
    0 => 
    array (
        'id' => 6154353459,
        'name' => 'pro one Night Out Mesh Tee',
        'display_brand' => 'Widow',
        'qty' => 1,
        'price' => '28.0000',
        'special_price' => 0,
        'rule_price' => '',
        'attributes' => 
        array (
        0 => 'BLACK',
        1 => 'XX-Large',
        ),
        'option80' => 18,
        'option125' => 3457,
        'child_product_id' => 61535897,
        'giftcard' => '',
        'whole_preorder' => 0,
        'preorder_shipping_date' => NULL,
        'available_qty' => 5,
        'isRefundable' => true,
        'max_sale_qty' => false,
        'isFree' => 0,
        'segment' => 
        array (
        'magento_product_id' => '65315459',
        'product_id' => 'P19335935',
        'quantity' => 1,
        'name' => 'pro one Night Out Mesh Tee',
        'brand' => 'Widow',
        'price' => 28.0,
        'special_price' => NULL,
        'regular_price' => 28.0,
        'size_type' => 'Regular',
        'manufacturer' => 'Widow',
        'trend' => 'WID goodie Hour 2020',
        'microcategory' => 'Mesh Shirt',
        'doll_category' => NULL,
        'stock_quantity' => 10,
        'sku' => 'S493660',
        'child_stock_quantity' => 1,
        'size' => 'XX-Large',
        'swatch' => 'BLACK',
        ),
    ),
    5 => 
    array (
        'id' => 615345465,
        'name' => 'pro one Night Out Mesh Leggings',
        'display_brand' => 'Widow',
        'qty' => 1,
        'price' => '30.0000',
        'special_price' => 0,
        'rule_price' => '',
        'attributes' => 
        array (
        0 => 'BLACK',
        1 => 'Medium',
        ),
        'option80' => 18,
        'option125' => 3454,
        'child_product_id' => 6315890,
        'giftcard' => '',
        'whole_preorder' => '',
        'preorder_shipping_date' => NULL,
        'available_qty' => 37,
        'isRefundable' => true,
        'max_sale_qty' => false,
        'isFree' => 0,
        'segment' => 
        array (
        'magento_product_id' => '64334515465',
        'product_id' => 'P193936',
        'quantity' => 1,
        'name' => 'pro one Night Out Mesh Leggings',
        'brand' => 'Widow',
        'price' => 30.0,
        'special_price' => NULL,
        'regular_price' => 30.0,
        'size_type' => 'Regular',
        'manufacturer' => 'Widow',
        'trend' => 'WID goodie Hour 2020',
        'microcategory' => 'Printed Leggings',
        'doll_category' => NULL,
        'stock_quantity' => 10,
        'sku' => 'S493664',
        'child_stock_quantity' => 10,
        'size' => 'Medium',
        'swatch' => 'BLACK',
        ),
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
        'id' => 615445348,
        'name' => 'pro two My Lashes Sunglasses',
        'display_brand' => '',
        'qty' => 1,
        'price' => '15.0000',
        'special_price' => 0,
        'rule_price' => '',
        'attributes' => 
        array (
        0 => 'BLACK',
        1 => 'ONE SIZE',
        ),
        'option80' => 18,
        'option125' => 6212,
        'child_product_id' => 6154345358,
        'giftcard' => '',
        'whole_preorder' => '',
        'preorder_shipping_date' => NULL,
        'available_qty' => 295,
        'isRefundable' => true,
        'max_sale_qty' => false,
        'isFree' => 0,
        'segment' => 
        array (
        'magento_product_id' => '6153453448',
        'product_id' => 'P19645642180',
        'quantity' => 1,
        'name' => 'pro two My Lashes Sunglasses',
        'brand' => '',
        'price' => 15.0,
        'special_price' => NULL,
        'regular_price' => 15.0,
        'size_type' => 'Regular',
        'manufacturer' => 'CIEL',
        'trend' => 'WID goodie Hour 2020',
        'microcategory' => 'Cat Eye Sunglasses',
        'category' => 'Accessories,Sunglasses,Cat Eye Sunglasses',
        'special_category' => 'What\'s New,Char Test Category,Widow',
        'doll_category' => NULL,
        'stock_quantity' => 10,
        'sku' => 'S486477',
        'child_stock_quantity' => 10,
        'size' => 'ONE SIZE',
        'swatch' => 'BLACK',
        ),
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
        'id' => 61465645461,
        'name' => 'pro one Night Out goodie Dress',
        'display_brand' => 'Widow',
        'qty' => 1,
        'price' => '45.0000',
        'special_price' => 0,
        'rule_price' => '',
        'attributes' => 
        array (
        0 => 'BLACK',
        1 => 'X-Large',
        ),
        'option80' => 18,
        'option125' => 3456,
        'giftcard' => '',
        'whole_preorder' => '',
        'preorder_shipping_date' => NULL,
        'available_qty' => 12,
        'isRefundable' => true,
        'max_sale_qty' => false,
        'isFree' => 0,
        'segment' => 
        array (
        'magento_product_id' => '616465461',
        'product_id' => 'P1935446934',
        'quantity' => 1,
        'name' => 'pro one Night Out goodie Dress',
        'brand' => 'Widow',
        'price' => 45.0,
        'special_price' => NULL,
        'regular_price' => 45.0,
        'size_type' => 'Regular',
        'manufacturer' => 'Widow',
        'trend' => 'WID goodie Hour 2020',
        'microcategory' => 'goodie Dresses',
        'category' => 'Clothing,Dresses,Mini,goodie Dresses',
        'special_category' => 'Brandsgoodie,Char Test Category,Widow,Widow',
        'doll_category' => NULL,
        'stock_quantity' => 10,
        'sku' => 'S493652',
        'child_stock_quantity' => 10,
        'size' => 'X-Large',
        'swatch' => 'BLACK',
        ),
    ),
    4 => 
    array (
        'id' => 6154566225,
        'name' => 'Feelings Maxi Dress',
        'display_brand' => 'Widow',
        'qty' => 1,
        'price' => '58.0000',
        'special_price' => 0,
        'rule_price' => '',
        'attributes' => 
        array (
        0 => 'BLACK',
        1 => 'Large',
        ),
        'option80' => 18,
        'option125' => 3455,
        'child_product_id' => 61456455677,
        'giftcard' => '',
        'whole_preorder' => '',
        'preorder_shipping_date' => NULL,
        'available_qty' => 30,
        'isRefundable' => true,
        'max_sale_qty' => false,
        'isFree' => 0,
        'segment' => 
        array (
        'magento_product_id' => '614565225',
        'product_id' => 'P1945652050',
        'quantity' => 1,
        'name' => 'Phantom Feelings Maxi Dress',
        'brand' => 'Widow',
        'price' => 58.0,
        'special_price' => NULL,
        'regular_price' => 58.0,
        'size_type' => 'Regular',
        'manufacturer' => 'Widow',
        'trend' => 'WID goodie Hour 2020',
        'microcategory' => 'Maxi Dresses',
        'category' => 'Dresses,Midi & Maxi,Maxi Dresses',
        'special_category' => 'Brandsgoodie,Char Test Category,Widow,Widow',
        'doll_category' => NULL,
        'stock_quantity' => 10,
        'sku' => 'S485794',
        'child_stock_quantity' => 10,
        'size' => 'Large',
        'swatch' => 'BLACK',
        ),
    )
    );

if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'] = $cart_array;
} else {
    $_SESSION['cart'] = (array) $_SESSION['cart'];
}

$itemId = 3;

if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$itemId])) {
    unset($_SESSION['cart'][$itemId]);
}

print_r($_SESSION['cart']);
```

Now it will be not back the remove item again, unless if you destroy the session

Comment: what will be here -$cart_array = // Your session default array here ? default array which one ? you mean session cart array ?

Comment: i mean your the array set of your data

Comment: It does not seems to be working. can you please review code in answer. I hope you understand the issue.   When i move product to delete on frontend
it unset an item from session array.

Then i move another item to delete.
the item which was unset is back in session array.

Comment: yes because the array in session is get the original array so the previous deleted is useless, you need to save the modified array in array and delete other item

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224462/discussion-between-dev-and-jerson).

Comment: Any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Why is there `$item['id']` used in `$stmt->bind_param(` (instead of `$id`?). `$item` is not a parameter of the function.

Similarly, where does the variable `$i` come from in `$itemId = $i;`?

I have written a simplified version of your problem and it works as expected. It uses a form and buttons to give the array indices to the PHP script. If you have a different setup (like using Ajax) you need to clarify that.

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['cart']) || sizeof($_SESSION['cart']) === 0)
 {
  echo('Resetting cart.' . PHP_EOL);
  $_SESSION['cart'] = [0 =>'zero', 1 =>'one', 2 =>'two', 3 =>'three', 4 =>'four'];
 }

echo('<pre>before ' . print_r($_SESSION['cart'], TRUE) . '</pre>');

$itemId = isset($_GET['itemid']) ? $_GET['itemid'] : FALSE;
if ($itemId !== FALSE)
 {
  if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$itemId]))
   {
    echo('Unsetting &raquo;' . $itemId . '&laquo;.' . PHP_EOL);
    unset($_SESSION['cart'][$itemId]);
   }
  else
    echo('&raquo;' . $itemId . '&laquo; not in cart.' . PHP_EOL);
 }
else
  echo('No item ID given.' . PHP_EOL);

echo('<pre>after ' . print_r($_SESSION['cart'], TRUE) . '</pre>');

echo('<form method="get" action="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '">' . PHP_EOL);
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key=>$value)
  echo('<button name="itemid" value="' . $key .  '">' . $value . '</button>' . PHP_EOL);
echo('</form>' . PHP_EOL);
```

Answer (score 0):

The manual has made it clear

If a globalized variable is unset() inside of a function, only the local variable is destroyed. The variable in the calling environment will retain the same value as before unset() was called.

To unset() a global variable inside of a function, then use the $GLOBALS array to do so:

```
<?php
function foo() 
{
    unset($GLOBALS['bar']);
}

$bar = "something";
foo();
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $item['id'],$cartId);
$stmt->execute();
```

where is `$item['id']` from?

Try using different variable names on your bind_param and declare their value before query execute() method.